# Is it possible to run Horizon server on Windows?

Tags: django, python-2.7, openstack, openstack-horizon

I'm using windows as my development machine. Recently we are developing some features on OpenStack Horizon. Which means we need to checkout horizon source code from github:

> https://github.com/openstack/horizon

Then I tried to follow the document to start horizon Django service on Windows. But it failed. But on Linux(Ubuntu virtual machine) it works fine.

Does anyone ever been able to start Horizon Django server on windows?

Comment: You'd better develop it in Linux visualization operating system. It's hard to meet the development environment in Windows or Mac.

Comment: I suppose so, after checking the source code, I believe the developers didn't even consider it supporting Windows. They use hard coded '/' instead of cross-platform attributes like os.path.sep. I thought I could modify it to support Windows, but there are just too many places need this kind of modification.